# Negative of a compact set is compact proof?

Tags: real-analysis

Let S ⊆ R be compact. Prove that the set −S is also compact.

I know that it has something along the lines of first proving that if U ⊆ R is open then so is −U, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are quicker (I guess), but from definition if you take an open cover $C$ of $-S$ then $-C$ is an open cover of $S$ and since $S$ is compact there is a finite subcover of $-C$. Can you finish now?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=-x$ is continuous and continuous image of a compact set is compact.

If you want to use the definition of compactness you can observe that $f$ is actually a homeomorphism. Hence $-U$ is open whenever $U$ is open. Now if $(U_i)$ is an open cover of $-S$ then $(-U_i)$ is an open cover of $S$ so there is a finite subcover. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $-S$. Then $(-x_n)$ is a sequence in $S$. Since $S$ is compact, there is a convergent subsequence $(-x_{n_k})$ with limit $a \in S$.

Hence $(x_{n_k})$ is a convergent sequence in $-S$ with limit $-a \in S.$